# Problems with flexible discriminant analysis

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to do a flexible discriminant analysis,using measurements taken on bones, but i need to apply `MARS` as a method using R ,however for some reason, only for some of my dataframes R give me a warning

**Warning message:**

`In fda(SEX ~ ., data = hex, method = mars) :   degenerate problem; no discrimination`

Can anybody please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

hex <- "Sex       age         hdl        hdb
1          F         0              8.4         20.41
2          F         0              7.4         15.40
3          F         9              7.3         19.40
4          M         9             13.5       37.31
5          M         11          14.4        43.49
6          M         11          15.7         40.10   “

hex=read.table("hex.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

str(hex)

hex[2:3] <- lapply(hex[2:3], as.numeric)

hexfit <- fda(SEX~ ., data =hex,method=mars)

Warning message: In fda(SEX ~ ., data = hex, method = mars) : degenerate problem; no discrimination

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of the data and code that produces the error, it's difficult to tell what might be causing your error if we can't see the code that led to it. See [mcve] and [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is zz the same data as hex and humerus? Please edit question to make your code reproducible.